# Pass data from one fragmentation to another fragmentation function

Tags: android, android-fragments

Now I am trying to pass data from one fragment to another fragment method.

for Example,

Fragment one

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 //DB Connection
 ...
 ...
values_description = stringArrayList_description.toArray(new String[stringArrayList_description.size()]);
 Fragmenttwo frag_two = new Fragmenttwo();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("data","data12344");
frag_two.setArguments(args);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.text_view,frag_two);
//Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"position"+parent.getItemAtPosition(position),Toa    st.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

Second Fragment

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview_two, container, false);
    textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    value = bundle.getString("data","nulll");
    setData(value);
    return view;
}

public void setData(String data){
    textView.setText(data);
}
```

But I can't able to receive the data from the second fragmentation, it throws error like,

```
04-07 11:24:03.887 2937-2937/com.ats.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ats.test, PID: 2937                      
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at fragments.Callhistory_Fragment.onCreateView(Callhistory_Fragment.java:35)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at fragments.Fragmenttwo.onCreateView(Fragmenttwo.java:27)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4877)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
at fragments.Callhistory_Fragment.onCreateView(Callhistory_Fragment.java:35) 
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890) 
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062) 
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453) 
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Fragment to handle another fragments (fragmentone and fragmenttwo)

```
 <fragment
    android:layout_width="206dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:name="fragments.Fragmentone"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"></fragment>

 <fragment
    android:layout_width="164dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:name="fragments.Fragmenttwo"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    ></fragment>

   </FrameLayout>
```

R.Layout.fragment_listview_two.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f467f7">
 <TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/text_view"
android:text="description \n here"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please guide me, I don't know where I did mistake.

Comment: post your fragment_listview_two.xml... It contains error...

Comment: as your log says there is a issue in inflating xml , its not a issue of data passing.

Comment: how to resolve this inflating issue and also i got NullPointerException too i don't know where this exception is thrown

Comment: show Activity code where you handle fragments. than solve this problem.

Comment: Check this lines in xml and fragment first or post it here:

Binary XML file line #13: of
Callhistory_Fragment.onCreateView(Callhistory_Fragment.java:35)
Fragmenttwo.onCreateView(Fragmenttwo.java:27)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This..

In you FromFragment:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment(); // replace your custom fragment class 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
bundle.putString("key","value"); // use as per your need
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(viewID,fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In custom fragment class

```
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle = getArguments();
mBundle.getString(key);
```

// key must be same which was given in first fragment

Comment: Please explain me clearly about line getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.body, toFragment, TAG_TO_FRAGMENT)
    .addToBackStack(TAG_TO_FRAGMENT).commit();

Comment: replace(R.id.body, toFragment,frag_two ).addToBackStack(frag_two OR null) .commit();

Comment: I tried with .commit() but it shows error like "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup"

Comment: i think in second page TEXTVIEW cast exception error. check this textView.setText(" "+data);

Comment: I commented that line textView.setText(""+data); but still it throws error "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup"

Comment: can you please explain me what you mentioned viewID in this line  fragmentTransaction.replace(viewID,fragment);

Comment: try to debug you app put break point on or above Textview Line..n tell me whats log given...

Comment: ViewID Is your container layout Id that one fragment replace by other fragment. For example you have one Frame layout as a container and all another fragment replaced one by one....

Answer (score 0):

Try it!!!!

add bundle != null at

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview_two, container, false);
textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if(bundle != null){

value = bundle.getString("data");
setData(value);
}

return view;
}

public void setData(String data){
textView.setText(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your Fragment like this :

```
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.text_view,frag_two).commit();
```

Comment: I tried as you said, but i got error like java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Comment: @ShivaKumar can you post R.layout.fragment_listview_two or tell me you have declared AppCompatTextView  or TextView there ?

Comment: I posted R.layout.fragment_listview_two.xml and i used textview there

Comment: where you are using AppCompatTextView ! in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple pass any data to the second fragment's constructor.

```
String text = "test";


SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment(text);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Then at SecondFragment

```
String receivingText;


public SecondFragment(String text){
      this.receivingText = text;
}
```

Comment: we cant able to create a non-default constructor for fragment class

Comment: please explain exactly what you mean?

Comment: for any fragment extended class we cant able to create non-default constructor class (contstructor with some parameter)